# How do I use objective-c-runtime's object_getIvar & object_setIvar in swift?

Tags: swift, objective-c-runtime

Does anybody know why I get BAD_ACCESS on getting & setting of my iVars with the following code ?

```
class myClass: NSObject {
    var model = "Unspecified"

    override init() {
        super.init()

        var key: NSString = "model"
        var aClass : AnyClass? = self
        var ivar: Ivar = class_getInstanceVariable(aClass, key.UTF8String)

        // Set
        object_setIvar(aClass, ivar, "R56")

        // Get
        var value: AnyObject = object_getIvar(aClass, ivar)
    }

}

myClass()
```

Comment: The first problem is that you should be passing `self` as the first argument to `object_setIvar` and `object_getIvar`, but it still crashes/exhibits weird behavior after that. I suspect a bug.

Answer (score 1):

You get a bad access because Swift classes do not have traditional iVars anymore (try to grab a Swift class' iVar layout and see for yourself).  But Swift classes are also Objective-C objects to the runtime, and there don't appear to be any paths excluding Swift classes in it.

What winds up happening is the runtime hands you a bogus iVar that it truly thinks points to a proper offset in the class definition (probably 0 or thereabouts because it doesn't exist).  When you try to get said iVar, the runtime literally [derefs you some of the object's bytes and tries to wrap it back up in an Objective-C pointer](https://github.com/opensource-apple/objc4/blob/881b875d7aada4cbfc154e022e1297c9526de747/runtime/objc-class.mm#L360).  Often this data has the tagged bit set unintentionally, and so often maps to tagged classes (in my tests I was reliably getting back a tagged pointer for what the runtime thought was NSMutableData).

Long story short: you can't do it anymore.

Comment: Just read this and it makes great sense, explaining why my DI framework is having problems with setting ivars in swift classes. The question I have is this. If I want to set an internal var in a swift class. How can I do it? In Objective-C I can declare and set an internal variable which helps with keeping interfaces clean. Do I now have to expose everything as properties? That would suck. :-(